# Webcam doesn't work in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: hardware, webcam

I have Gembird cam68ut. On my Ubuntu 12.10 it shows black screen in cheese and guvcview. 
I tested it in win7, it works fine.

Here what I found:

- It is a uvc compliant camera, I checked on the [site](http://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/#devices):
  18ec:3299    USB 2.0 PC Camera (model number QC3231) ArkMicro
- This webcam is report by `lsusb`: `Bus 001 Device 004: ID 18ec:3299 Arkmicro Technologies Inc.`
- Here is the output of `dmesg | tail`:

  ```
  uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB2.0 PC CAMERA (18ec:3299)
  uvcvideo: UVC non compliance - GET_DEF(PROBE) not supported. Enabling workaround.
  input: USB2.0 PC CAMERA as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/input/input17
  usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
  USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
  ```
- When I run `cheese` (or `guvcview`), here what I get in terminal:

  ```
  libv4l2: error turning on stream: No space left on device
  (cheese:11797): cheese-WARNING **: Internal data flow error.
  ```
- I tried it on different usb slots with the same results
- The Webcam's microphone works, I can record audio with it

**Update:** I tested it on other two machines with the same Ubuntu and it works without problems having the same `dmseg | tail` message.

Guys, may be it is a bug with USB controller driver in the kernel (because on that machine camera works in win7)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested it on two other machines with the same Ubuntu and it worked out of the box.
It is a long known bug with USB host controller. 
I reported it on launchpad: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1088395. 
Also I found a very similar bug: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1088395